# WPDB always returning array(0)?

Tags: php, wordpress

The below query is always returning an empty array i have checked that the $_POST is working but i am unsure what is going on?

```
$database = new wpdb(QLBBackendUser, QLBBackendPass, QLBBackendDB, DB_HOST);  

if (isset($_POST['register-user'])):
    $user = $database->get_results('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='.$_POST["user_email"]);
    var_dump($user);
endif;
```

Please note this is for Wordpress using WPDB Class.

Comment: You should never call the `wpdb` class directly...Use the global `$wpdb` object instead...Read more [in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never call the `wpdb` class directly...If you must, use the global `$wpdb` object instead. In addition, make sure the `user_email` has been `POST`ed (I'm not sure why you're checking for `register-user` being set and not `user_email`). Also, it's highly unlikely that the table you should be querying is called `users` (without a prefix). It's likely `wp_users` if you're using the default prefix.

Finally, there is a handy function that already does what you're trying to re-implement, called [`get_user_by`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_by):

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', $_POST['user_email'] );
```

I recommend using the above, instead of trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: In addition, I would only suggest if @Elevant wants to keep the custom query, they can rewrite it as follows: `$wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->users} WHERE email=%s", $_POST['user_email'] ) );`. I believe it's important to point out the security hole that they had in their original query(using `$_POST` directly), even if it doesn't serve them now it is an important lesson to learn.

Comment: Are there security concerns in regards to calling wpdb directly? I have done it like that for a lot of pages. Also I didn't know about that function I should read more about them. Thanks

Comment: Also can you show me an example without calling wbdb directly? Or does it just mean to use the functions given like get user by function?

Comment: It's not unsafe to use the `$wpdb` object directly...however, it is unsafe to pass `$_POST` data directly to `$wpdb`. Instead you should [sanitize this data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_text_field), before passing it to `$wpdb`. And yes, using functions like `get_user_by()` is the way to do it withough `$wpdb`